# C++ Tokenize string not dereferencable

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, debugging, dereference

I am getting a "string not dereferencable" error for my code, which is pretty much copied verbatim from somewhere on the internet. The application compiles perfectly in release mode (VS 2010), however keeps throwing me an error in Debug mode. It should be splitting the string at the * and saving each of the words to a vector. Does anyone have any ideas? It really doesn't seem to like the (string::npos != found) part of the comparison.

```
string newString = "Something*NotCool";

size_t found = newString.find_first_of("+*-/%()");
size_t lastPos = 0;
//while (found != newString.length)
while (string::npos != found || string::npos != lastPos)
{
    if (found >= newString.length()) break;
    if (found == lastPos)
    {
        lastPos = found+1;
        found = newString.find_first_of("+*-/()", found+1);
    }
    string temp (newString,lastPos,found);
    temp.assign(newString, lastPos, found-lastPos);
    strings.push_back(temp);
    lastPos = found+1;
    found = newString.find_first_of("+*-/()", found + 1);
}
```

Your help is gratefully appreciated!!!

Comment: It compiles for me using VS 2010 (I used cl, not the IDE).  You're going to need to show more code.

Comment: Are you sure this is the code that throws the error?  I suspect that this is code that has some stuff added to avoid the error message, but instead it still has the problem that the last word doesn't get added to `strings`.  Also, please be careful about the distinction between compiler errors and runtime errors - they're quite different, and saying something 'compiles perfectly' is different than saying it runs without error messages (which is yet again different than saying it runs correctly).

Comment: I think your `if (found == lastPos)` logic is off. This seems to try detecting when there are two *s in a row, and to ignore them. However, 3 or more *s in a row would not be caught.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code didn't produce any errors for me in VS2010.

Since you've got access to regular expressions (`<regex>` library), another alternative could be:

```
std::string str = "Something*NotCool";
std::regex re("[^(\\*\\+%/\\-\\(\\))]+");
std::sregex_token_iterator begin(str.begin(), str.end(), re), end;
std::vector<std::string> tokens;
std::copy(begin, end, std::back_inserter(tokens));
```

Comment: This is EPIC. Thanks so much for your help. I just added a \\/ in the re(...) to ensure that it processes the divide symbol (I hope I did that right - sort of an ad-hoc test). Looks like I have some reading up to do on these "new" features. Thanks again!

Comment: I like how having to escape the regex escapes makes it explode into something a bit mesmerizing. It's its own little "Where's Waldo?" for the set of delimiter characters. And don't forget that the `'%'` shouldn't always be there (or maybe that was another bug in the original code...)

Comment: @MichaelBurr: Thats probably why c++11 introduced raw string literals.